# how to convert a datatable to List<long,List<keyvaluepair<string,string>>> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I have a datatable with three columns says, ID, Name and Value.

I want to convert this datatable into `List<long,List<keyvaluepair<string,string>>>`.

The only trick is ID is foreign ket from another table. so it could have repeatative values.

I want to do it in C#.

Thanks in advance.

---

no, not dictionaly.....actualy I have two classes says, definded as....

```
public class RunParameters
    {
        public long RunId { get; set; }
        public List<WorkflowParameter<string>> WorkflowParameters { get; set; }

        public RunParameters()
        {
            WorkflowParameters = new List<WorkflowParameter<string>>();
        }
    }

 public struct WorkflowParameter<T>
    {
        public string ParameterName
        { get; set; }
        public T ParameterValue
        { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to convert the datable into List.

I cannot use dictionary since I want to serialize the this List to send it across the network....

Comment: Do you mean `Dictionary<long,List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>`?

Comment: Kindly see the updates....

Comment: A list can be of one type only - so, if you want a list it would have to be `List<KeyValuePair<long, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>>` which is ugly even only when defining it. Is that really what you want?

Comment: By *datatable* you mean `DataTable` class? And how your classes related to initial question?

Comment: Hello Joanna, What exectly I want is...I have datatable with three columns says, ID, Name and Value. I want to convert that datatable into List<RunParameters>. THis RunParameters contain two variable Id and workflowParameter. THis workflowParameter again contain two fields called name and value. So ultimate output I want is List<long,List<WorkflowParamete<string>>>.

for class mapping, you can refer my question.

Answer (score 2):

Group items in your query by `ID` and project each item from group to `KeyValuePair`:

```
(from r in table.AsEnumerable()
 group r by r.Field<long>("ID") into g
 select g.Select(i => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                      i.Field<string>("Name"), i.Field<string>("Value"))
         .ToList()).ToList()
```

Or completely with method syntax:

```
 table.AsEnumerable()
      .GroupBy(r => r.Field<long>("ID"))
      .Select(g => g.Select(r => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                          r.Field<string>("Name"), r.Field<string>("Value"))
                    .ToList())
      .ToList()
```